# Python No module error

Tags: python

Following console output explains the issue

```
$ ls -r *
b:
y.py        __init__.py    
a:
x.pyc       x.py        __init__.pyc    __init__.py

L-IDC42NDV7M-M:pytest rohit$ python    
>>> import a.x as xx
>>> print xx.v
1

$ python b/y.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b/y.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a.x as xx
ImportError: No module named a.x
```

If python looks at current working directory for modules shouldn't 'python b/y.py' find a/x.py?

> In Java sibling modules can be imported. I am looking for something
>   similar in python.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should move a directory in b directory!

Comment: Is it possible without moving it? Lets say these are 2 different modules under a main module.

Comment: I think it's better to make main file for calling other files.like route file.or manage.py file in Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not search for current directory (`.`). But it search for the directory that containing the input script (`./b`). See [The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

If you want current directory to be search, you can use `PYTHONPATH=.`

```
PYTHONPATH=. python b/y.py
```

or using [`-m` option](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

```
python -m b.y
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory of the main program is automatically added to Python path. The module name of the main program is `__main__`, not `b.y`

You can either write a simple main program that is in the parent directory of a and b, or you can add that parent directory to PYTHONPATH.

If you call `python very/long/path/to/the/main/program.py` it does not mean that the current directory is the root of a deep namespace. I think, in Java is the main program relative deep in the namespace and therefore everything is different.